# Need to sort dict values and print highest value pair using Django Python

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views

As i am using Python for backend and Django for frontend.

Currently i am getting output in background as below from function:

```
d={'Testcase1': {'hydra.c': 10,'clone.c':5},
 'Testcase2':{'hydra.c':337,'vendor.c':100 },
 'Testcase3':{'hydra.c':100,'vendor.c':80}
 'Testcase4':{'vendor.c':89,'template.c':98,'temp.c':92},
 'Testcase5':{'vendor.c':83}
 'Testcase6':{'template.c':34}....}

for key,values in d.iteritems():
    so=sorted(values.iteritems(),key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    print(key,so[-1][0],so[-1][1])
```

for backend i'm getting correct output but how to implement this function in Django frontend

```
{% for key,value in d.items() %}
{% for k,v in sorted(value.iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v): (v,k)):
<table>
  <tr>
   <td>{{ key }}</td>
   <td>{{ k[-1] }}</td>
   <td>{{ v[-1] }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: can you just append the dict to a list in the view then render it in template ?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you build a dictionary on backend and then render the template with created dict.

```
d={'Testcase1': {'hydra.c': 10,'clone.c':5},
 'Testcase2':{'hydra.c':337,'vendor.c':100 },
 'Testcase3':{'hydra.c':100,'vendor.c':80}
 'Testcase4':{'vendor.c':89,'template.c':98,'temp.c':92},
 'Testcase5':{'vendor.c':83}
 'Testcase6':{'template.c':34}....}
out_dict = {}
for key,values in d.iteritems():
    so=sorted(values.iteritems(),key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    out_dict[key] = [so[-1][0],so[-1][1]]
```

in UI,

```
{% for key, value in out_dict.items %}
<table>
  <tr>
   <td>{{ key }}</td>
   <td>{{ value.0 }}</td>
   <td>{{ value.1 }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
{% endfor %}
```